# Know about AWS Golden Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

What is AWS "Golden Image"? 
I would like to know how is it different from the AMI images that we create normally.

Comment: Sometimes I think Stack Overflow is moderated by inflexible robots with no human intervention whatsoever.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no difference. A golden image is simply an image that you have customized to your liking with all necessary software/data/configuration information ready to go and then saved as a personal AMI from which you can launch instances.

Comment: +1, just adding few more information. when deploying on AWS you have 2 main strategies: 1. Golden AMI, which is (as E.J Brennan says) building an AMI embedding all your code/config/packages/whatever is needed for your code to run; and 2. Deployment at spawn time using a a tool or set of tool like jenkins, chef, ec2 userdata script, AWS codeDeploy etc. with a Golden AMI you speed up the deployment, with spawn time deployment you get more agility in changes. you can of course end up with a mix of both techniques.

Comment: Thanks E.J and Tom :)